# How to connect to rabbit instance with url like ssl://some.openshitft.instance:443

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, openshift, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to connecto this rabbit MQ instance running on open shift but failing with connection error.

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:74) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:371) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1171) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1422) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:909) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 8 common frames omitted

2017-12-15 11:30:23.688 ERROR 9136 --- [.62.234.34:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured

java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Could anyone please provide any kind of help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the client running that is trying to connect to it? In the same OpenShift cluster? If the client is outside the cluster, how are you trying to expose the service running inside the cluster so it is accessible from outside of the cluster?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, currently, my client is outside of the cluster and i don't have access to open shift cluster environment. If you could let me know what changes should be needed to access that service to the outside world, I can suggest it to our respective team and can get the require changes in the running cluster/POD.

Comment: The only information that I  have with me is the url/route and rabbit mq username/password "url" :ssl://https://some.opeshit.instance/
"name": "adminuser",
"password": "adminpass",

Comment: If RabbitMQ is not actually a HTTP service, but they are trying to expose it outside of OpenShift using a route with pass through secure connection, that means their RabbitMQ instance must be terminating the secure connection itself. If this is what they are doing, your client must support Server Name Identification (SNI) over secure TLS connections. Have they said that the RabbitMQ is actually exposed and others can already access it?

Comment: broker-management   https://some.openshift.instance broker       15672-tcp         Edge
broker              https://some.openshift.instance broker       883-tcp           Passthrough 
This is how they have exposed the rabbit mq as service to outside world

Comment: So you can only use the latter using passthrough if is a non HTTP protocol, which requires RabbitMQ to terminate the secure connection and your client must support SNI over TLS. Does your client support SNI over TLS? If it doesn't then the OpenShift router will not be able to route the connection through to RabbitMQ.